# How to display a child DIV over the parent DIV (absolute, hidden)?

Tags: html, css

How can I display child div over parent div in this situation?

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.parent {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 3;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-decoration: inherit;
  text-align: center;
  color: inherit;
  left: 5px;
  top: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: red;
}
.child {
  position: relative;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 50px;
  height: 100px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bzf4ru29/2

Very important moment that I can't change a style of the parent div (this div has been generated by Eclipse RAP and I can't change it).

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bzf4ru29/2/

Comment: What do you mean with "over the parent div"?

Comment: I need the next result http://jsfiddle.net/bzf4ru29/4 but do not change parent DIV. Have you any ideas?

Comment: If you want a div to look like its sitting on top of your parent div either remove the `overflow:hidden;` or the div that sits on top cannot be contained within the parent

Comment: @Andrew But I can change the child DIV only

Comment: What do you mean by you can change the child div only?

Comment: I have the framework Eclipse RAP. It generate html code like parent DIV in my situation and I can't change it manually

Comment: Can you change the child and parent CSS? You need to properly explain what you can actually change. Can you add in new CSS also. then with that you can override the parent.

Comment: I can't touch html code and css style of parent DIV. But I can add whatever I want inside it.

Answer (score 0):

```
.parent {
position: relative;
/* overflow: hidden; */
z-index: 3;
white-space: nowrap;
text-decoration: inherit;
text-align: center;
color: inherit;
/* left: 5px; */
top: 10px;
width: 200px;
height: 30px;
background-color: red;}

.child {
position: absolute;
background-color: blue;
width: 50px;
height: 100px;
z-index: 100;}
```

Do you mean like this?

Comment: Yes, I do. I have the framework Eclipse RAP. It generate html code like parent DIV in my situation and I can't change it manually.

Answer (score 0):

```
with out changing parents style is not actual way of doing... But it is possible by, Changing child style from position: relative to absolute
     .child {
            position: relative;
            background-color: blue;
            width: 50px;
            height: 100px;
            }
```

Now your child div is above parent div

Answer (score 0):

the answer
 **change this**

```
.child {  position: relative;  background-color: blue;  width: 50px;
```

height: 100px;}

or run this snippet

```html
<html><head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title> - jsFiddle demo</title>
  
  
  
  
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">
  
  <style type="text/css">
    .parent {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-decoration: inherit;
  text-align: center;
  color: inherit;
  left: 5px;
  top: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: red;
}
.child {
  position: relative;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 50px;
  height: 100px;
}
  </style>
  




</head>
<body>
  



<div class="parent">
 <div class="child"></div>
</div>


  





</body></html>
```

Comment: I try to find the solution without editing parent div.

Comment: need to change parent div **one thing** don`t use **`position: absolute;`** or change **` overflow: auto;`**